# Systemtap does not find the tapping points

Tags: linux-kernel, systemtap

I was trying to compile my own kernel through `clang-13` and run `systemtap` on that. I have enabled the `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL` and all other default debugging configs including `CONFIG_KPROBES`, `CONFIG_UPROBES`. Additionally I have disabled `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE`. To compile and install I ran `make -j8 bindeb-pkg && sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb`. As you can see from the screenshot below the `dbg` package was installed and the sha256 confirms that the vmlinux matches, so systemtap should have access to its symbols. However, that doesn't seem to be the case since systemtap fails.

Additionally I compile the latest systemtap with `clang-13` as follows `make -j8 CC=clang-13 CXX=clang++-13 CFLAGS="-Wno-error" CXXFLAGS="-Wno-error"`.

The systemtap version is `4.7/0.170` and it says `tested kernel versions: 2.6.32 ... 5.15.0-rc7`. I might be missing something here.

[image: Installed kernel's version]

Answer (score 0):

Tracepoints in stap are identified by chewing through kernel headers (and sometimes sources).  You can check whether stap is finding them with greater verbosity, such as:

```
stap -k -p2 --poison-cache --vp 04 -e 'probe ....'
```

If it's working, you'll see a lot of compiler invocations related to "tracequery", and you can see the residue of the searches under $TMPDIR (due to the `-k` option).